# Angular timer is flickering because of the component destroy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, count, timer

I have a parent component where I get the data from BE and where I pass the data to the child component:

```
<app-team-tile [teamData]="team" (openNotes)="openNotes($event)"></app-team-tile>
```

teamData represents a collection of team members. In the teamTile component I pass the data to a next child component:

```
<app-team-firefighter
   [firefighter]="firefighter"
   [longestAlarm]="getTheLongestFirefighterAlarm(firefighter)"
 ></app-team-firefighter>
```

the longestAlarm is a method that returns an alarm to the child component. In the **app-team-firefighter** component I have a timer in the ngOnChanges method:

```
 ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.longestAlarm) {
      interval(1000).pipe(
        map((count: any) => this.format(count + this.longestAlarm.duration))
      ).subscribe((time: string) => {
        this.timer = time;
      });
    }
  }
```

In the template I display the `this.timer` value, but it flickers every 5 seconds because I get data from BE every 5 seconds, and I know that when I get data from BE in the parent, the child destroys. What can I do to remove this flicker. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing this in `ngOnChanges` -> this lifecycle hook is called everytime an input value changes. But you are not using these change values, so you should move your subscription to `ngOnInit`.

If you are changing your inputs every 5 seconds, you are creating a new subscription each time the method runs! (probably causing your flicker). You are also not cleaning these up from what I can see so you are just making duplicate subscriptions every 5 seconds which will cause a memory leak.

You will want to unsubscribe! (I haven't included this below)

```
ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000).pipe(
         filter(_ => !!this.longestAlarm),
         map((count: any) => this.format(count + this.longestAlarm.duration))
     ).subscribe((time: string) => {
         this.timer = time;
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your solution, but the issue is still present.